# Working when run, but not when built

Tags: node.js, macos, electron

Im on macOS. I am creating a simple electron app. When I run the app with `electron .` everything works perfectly with no errors. Now that my app is finished, I wanted to build and distribute it. So I setup `electron-builder` and I got that to work just fine. However, when I run the `MyApp.app` in the build folder, I get an error saying:

```
Uncaught Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir './img/'
```

I call `scandir` here:

```
  const fs = require('fs');
  var files = [];
  fs.readdirSync("./img/").forEach(file => {
    files.push(file);
  })
```

Why is this working when I run it with node, but is not working in the build? How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is this working when I run it with node, but is not working in the
>   build? How can I fix this issue?

It's difficult to tell without having more information about the whole app's structure, it may depend on how your code is actually called or required from the html file.

Anyway, using the `__dirname` global variable to build the directory path usually solves this kind of problem. Please try:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

var files = [];
fs.readdirSync(path.join(__dirname, 'img')).forEach(file => {
    files.push(file);
});
```

Comment: This worked. I have been on this issue for about 3 hours now. Thank you so much.